# Email only Errors/Warnings with Microsoft Logging Application Block 3.1.0.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, logging, enterprise-library

What am I doing wrong?

I'm trying to configure the logging settings to log all events in a database and event viewer  but email only errors and warnings.  Database and Event Viewer part works fine except that I'm not getting any email for errors. Am I missing something?

> Note: There isn't any problem with
>   smtp settings because I get event's
>   emails if I add the listener to
>   "General" and "All events" in category
>   sources.

Here is my config:  (I'm using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging 3.1.0.0)

```
    <loggingConfiguration name="Logging Application Block" tracingEnabled="true" defaultCategory="General" logWarningsWhenNoCategoriesMatch="false">
    <listeners>
      <add databaseInstanceName="LOGGING_DB" writeLogStoredProcName="WriteLog"
              addCategoryStoredProcName="AddCategory" formatter="Text Formatter"
              listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Database.Configuration.FormattedDatabaseTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Database, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
              traceOutputOptions="None" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Database.FormattedDatabaseTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Database, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
              name="Database Trace Listener" />

      <add toAddress="jafet@jafet.com" fromAddress="jafet@jafet.com" subjectLineStarter="My App" subjectLineEnder="QA" smtpServer="SMTP1.jafet.com" smtpPort="25" formatter="Text Formatter" listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.EmailTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" traceOutputOptions="None" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.EmailTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" name="Email TraceListener"/>
      <add source="My Application" formatter="Text Formatter" log="" machineName="." listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.FormattedEventLogTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" traceOutputOptions="None" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.FormattedEventLogTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" name="Event Log Destination"/>
    </listeners>
    <formatters>
      <add template="Timestamp: {timestamp}&#xA;Message: {message}&#xA;Category: {category}&#xA;Priority: {priority}&#xA;EventId: {eventid}&#xA;Severity: {severity}&#xA;Title:{title}&#xA;Machine: {machine}&#xA;Application Domain: {appDomain}&#xA;Process Id: {processId}&#xA;Process Name: {processName}&#xA;Win32 Thread Id: {win32ThreadId}&#xA;Thread Name: {threadName}&#xA;Extended Properties: {dictionary({key} - {value}&#xA;)}" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Formatters.TextFormatter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" name="Text Formatter"/>
    </formatters>
    <categorySources>
      <add switchValue="All" name="General">
        <listeners>
          <add name="Event Log Destination"/>
          <add name="Database Trace Listener" />
        </listeners>
      </add>
    </categorySources>
    <specialSources>
      <allEvents switchValue="All" name="All Events">
        <listeners>
          <add name="Event Log Destination"/>
          <add name="Database Trace Listener" />
        </listeners>
      </allEvents>
      <notProcessed switchValue="All" name="Unprocessed Category"/>
      <errors switchValue="All" name="Logging Errors &amp; Warnings">
        <listeners>
          <add name="Database Trace Listener" />
          <add name="Event Log Destination"/>
          <add name="Email TraceListener"/>
        </listeners>
      </errors>
    </specialSources>
  </loggingConfiguration>
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this reply is very late...

I was also facing the same problem. I just read here (http://www.thejoyofcode.com/Log_Event_to_Listener_Routing_in_Enterprise_Library.aspx) that the error and warnings special source is for internal logging errors, ex if the logger cannot log to DB due to a broken db connection.. if you want to log your app errors create a separate category and log to that.

Cheers,
Mahesh